# .NET 4.8 webapi migrate to .net6 issue with WrongEnum value

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-6.0, system.text.json, .net-4.8

I am migrating an old .NET 4.8 Web API to .NET 6 and realized an issue with Json conversion. For example, this is an example Web API in .NET 4.8:

```
    public enum SampleEnum
    {
        Bar,
        Baz,
    }
    public class Jerry
    {
        public SampleEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
    }
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        // POST api/values
        public void Post([FromBody] Jerry value)
        {
            var a = value;
        }
    }
```

If the request is one with clearly wrong value:

```
{  
   "MyEnum":  "MonthEnd"       
}
```

Above webapi in .net 4.8 will use the default value for the enum (Bar).

For the same code in .net 6 with NewtonJson or Json.Text, it will throw exception saying I can't understand MonthEnd.

.net 6 is the right behaviour as the user passed a wrong value, but my problem is that our webapi is already on production for very long and we can't risk a sudden surge of customer complain.

Is there a way to mimic the .net 4.8's behaviour (i.e. if an enum value can't be understood, we fallback to deafult )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround with custom converter. For example something like the following:

```cs
class CustomEnumConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T: struct, Enum
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse<T>(reader.GetString(), out var r))
        {
            return r;
        }
        return default;
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("G"));
}
```

And then mark corresponding property with it:

```
public class Jerry
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomEnumConverter<SampleEnum>))]
    public SampleEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you need to do it globally - create a [converter factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter) which will reuse this converter.

Comment: hi, I see. This works for most scenarios. But our QA throw me this request:
{  
   "MyEnum":  ["MonthEnd","DayEnd","YearEnd"]       
}
Above won't work will this crazy test(throws exception). Is there a way?

Comment: @daxu I would argue that is an invalid json which should throw on post. But you can check if json array is passed and return default in this case.